# Hypothesis testing: 95% confidence intervals of group means overlapping zero or 83% confidence intervals?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value

I am trying to select between the following two methods to look for significant differences between two abundance estimates: 1) calculation of the 95% confidence interval for the difference between the two group means to determine if confidence intervals overlap zero, and 2) 83% confidence intervals. I realise that interpretation of the overlap in 83% confidence intervals should only be undertaken when standard errors are approximately equal. I was wondering whether there are any factors that might affect the reliability of the first method for hypothesis testing?